# dropdownlist postback (different prob)

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, webforms

hi guys i have a weird prob here..
i have this dropdownlist where different values will hide/show some of the textbox in the page

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
              <asp:ListItem>Multiple Choice Question</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Free text answer</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

C# code behind, inside `Page_Load`:

```
   if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Multiple Choice Question")
        {
            tb_ans.Visible = true;
            tb_ans2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            tb_ans2.Visible = false;
            tb_ans.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) //the code within this statement will only load
    {
        Session["no"] = null;
        this.opt3.Attributes["style"] = "display: none;";
        .....
        opt3.Visible = false;
        ....
    }
```

Tried to debug and the result was : (i set breakpoint in page load)
when i select different value from the dropdownlist.
3rd time on changing the value, it looks like the dropdownlist keep the same value as the 2nd value.

the loop always go to the if(ddl.selectedvalue=="multiple...")
. As a result, it will not hide the textbox that i want if the value is change to "free text..."

example :

1. default selection 'multiple choice..'
2. change to 'free ans..' will hide the textbox but other button is not firing.
3. change back to 'multiple choice...' it will turn back to 'free ans..'
4. ddl.selected value is still multiple choice.

what is the problem here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this: `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`

Remove that.

That means it only works for the first time of the page load.

If you remove that, that function will run for every page load.

But why don't you use the `dropdownlist selected index change event`??

That's better.

Don't forget to add `AutoPostBack="true"` in your aspx `dropdownlist`

Ok. I want to write like this.

in aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="multiple">Multiple Choice Question</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="free">Free text answer</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

in cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.PostBack)
    {//write your other things which are not related to DropDownList1  }
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().Contains("multiple"))
    {
        ////do something
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().Contains("free"))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i removed that code from !page and move it to dropdownlist selected index. However, like what i said, it will not successful on the 2nd change event. refer to my example explanation above

Comment: Not very clear what's not working.. what do you mean by other button is not firing? After you put it inside `selectedIndexChange` event, put a break point and track it.. let me know wht's the problem..

Comment: I put breakpoint on the selectedIndexChange, the first change it went to the breakpoint n go smoothly. However, if i tried to change it back to the other value, it nvr reaches the breakpoint.
At the sametime, other button inside the page (inserting into db) is not firing too.

Comment: In that case, put 2 break points. one at the start of `PageLoad` another at `SelectedIndexChange`. Did you put any `try-catch` in `PageLoad`?? or any `return` or something that stops to proceed to `SelectedIndexChange`??

Comment: no. i did not put any try-catch in the pageload and no return aswell..
I put the breakpoint, the problem was, when i chose another ddl value (2nd time changing) the value of ddl inside page.postback = ddl.selectedvalue is still the previous answer. as a result no change in the textbox visibility.

Comment: I dun get `page.postback = ddl.selectedvalue`.. do you mean `if(Page.Postback){ddl.selectedvalue="some value";}` or `if(Page.Postback){string tempstr=ddl.selectedvalue;}` If the first one is the one u did, that's the problem.

Comment: Why dun you post your 2 events `PageLoad` and `SelectedIndexChange`. I will take a look

Comment: yeah i have updated my code. i removed the selectedindexchange and use another code on page load. please help.

Comment: I change my answer. take a look.. and try like my one if u r ok with it.. and let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: it wont even go through the if else.
Anw the main problem was, the dropdownlist 'refuse' to take in the new selected value.

Comment: Did you try using the `SelectedIndexChange`? well.. if it's not working, i can't really figure out what's the problem anymore? why dun u create a new dummy aspx page with nothing but the dropdownlist. And dun write anything in `PageLoad` and use `SelectedIndexChange`? In other words, use my method. I am pretty sure that it will work. From there come back to ur real page.

Comment: yeah i tried on a new webform just now. just a normal ddl to hide/show textbox. it works. 
i wonder why inside the current page is not working. 
it doesnt matter if its inside a table or masterpage right?

Comment: No it doesn't. What abt u migrate ur other controls to new page? Coz it happens to me once. Saying that the `Inherit` is not matched. I can't solve it at all as it is already matched coz I copied and pasted. I had to creat a new page and it is fine.

Comment: yo @william , found out the problem was because update panel.
once i remove the updatePanel, it postback like refreshing the page. but it perfectly working. thanks for all the support though :)
sorry to trouble you guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Multiple Choice Question" Value="Multiple Choice Question" Selected=selected></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Free text answer" Value="Free text answer"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: you use  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" so you have to raise this event as well in code behind

Comment: than dont write onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" on aspx page

Comment: then write code. for selected index change event, then only it will occur

Answer (score 0):

I think your `if` condition does exact opposite of what you want. The `Page.IsPostBack` property is `true` when the page is posted back from the dropdown list. You need to have it like this:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)  
{  
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Multiple Choice Question")  
    {  
        tb_ans.Visible = true;  
        tb_ans2.Visible = true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        tb_ans2.Visible = false;  
        tb_ans.Visible = false;
    }  
}
```

Comment: it will be the same if i put it outside the ifelse loop of the!page.Ispostback right?
then it will have the 2nd prob. please take a look at my example explanation

Comment: It will not be the same if you put it outside the `if (Page.IsPostBack)`. The condition ensures that the code will run only on postbacks to the page and not on the initial load of the page. Apart from that I don't know what you mean by _2. ... but other button is not firing_, you don't mention any other functionality than the dropdown hiding the textboxes. With the code correction I suggested this hides the textboxes based on dropdown selection also on subsequent postbacks.

Comment: yes it will hide the textboxes based on the DDL selection. 
your sugestion only works for the first 2 changes.
lets say the dll value was 'a' and 'b'.
default value is 'a'. first selection hides the textbox, then i change it back to 'a' it shows the TB. however, the next changing event doesnt do anything.

Comment: The code works for me for any number of DDL selection changes without any problem with these two options. Every selection does the postback and the stuff in code behind is performed correctly. As @william mentioned already, there may be something else being done on the page that does break this for you, if all the events on the page stop firing.

Comment: i have updated my question. could you take a look if there is any prob.